# How to send large files in an email in nodemailer

Tags: node.js, email, amazon-s3, attachment, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send emails from my platform to the users. The content which needs to be sent via email is inserted from a react form and attachments are uploaded to s3 bucket.
I first tried to send the s3 bucket file buffer string in the attachment content. It worked for smaller attachments, but not for larger once.
Since the nodemailer maximum email size is 10MB, I changed the code to send the s3 signed URL and it worked. But the issue is this link is expiring after 7 days. I don't want the links to expire. Code is as below,

```
    sendEmail: async (event) => {
      try {
       let {
        summary,
        description = undefined,
        attachments = [],
       } = event.body;
       let attachmentsArray = [];
       let emailPayload = {
          from: EMAIL_SENDER,
          to: EMAIL,
          subject: summary,
          text: description,
        };
        if (attachments.length > 0) {
          attachmentsArray = await Promise.all(attachments.map(async(attachment) => {
          const s3Response = await getDownloadUrl(BUCKET, attachment.filePath);
          return `File: <a href="${s3Response}">${attachment.fileName}</a><br>`
        }));
      
        let attachmentDownloadText = attachmentsArray.join(" ")
        emailPayload.html = `${emailPayload.text.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')} <br><br> Download attachments from here: <br><br> ${attachmentDownloadText}`
      }
      await sendEmail(emailPayload);
      return "success";
    } catch (err) {
      return err
    }
  },
  getDownloadUrl: async(bucket, filePath) => {
    try {
        const params = {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: filePath
          };
          const url = await s3.getSignedUrl('getObject',params);
          if(url){
            return url;
          }
          return null;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occurs while generating signed url ",error);
        return null;
    }
}
```

How to avoid link expiration or is there another way to send larger files in nodemailer?

Comment: Why not send an email with a link to an API you control, which then redirects to S3 as appropriate?